# RewriteRule gives HTTP 500 error

Tags: .htaccess

On my website, `www.example.com/` shows files which are in `/`, the root folder. But what I want is that `example.com/` shows files which are in `/www/`. So I add the following code in my `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]
```

But it displays a 500 error. Somebody could say to me what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]
```

It will rewrite the url once and stop the redirection loop.